Faild to resolve component quasar framework
i'm trying to import my custom components inside main layout file, using quasar faramework but i constently giving this message "failed to resolve component", if i import them directly in the index file which loads on the route "/", it works fine without any issues, but as soon as i import them in the main layout the error presist and the components don't render.
`Failed to resolve component: logo
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via              compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 

at <MainLayout onVnodeUnmounted=fn ref=Ref< undefined > >
at 
at `
i have tried to change quasar.congif.js, according to others solutions but it isn't worked, also
i added this section to "build" object like this :
chainWebpack(chain) {
    chain.module
      .rule("vue")
      .use("vue-loader")
      .tap((options) => {
        options.compilerOptions = {
          isCustomElement: (tag) => tag.startsWith("app-"),
        };
        return options;
      });
  },

also prefixed my custom components with "app-" but still get the message

Hey, I recommend using Vite rather than Webpack nowadays. If you create a brand new app using their CLI, you should have a working solution without any kind of headache regarding the config part. Here you go: https://quasar.dev/start/quasar-cli

"if i import them directly in the index file which loads on the route "/", it works fine without any issues, but as soon as i import them in the main layout" - can you clarify how do these two approaches look like? It's unclear if you rely on autoimport or else

Usually when you want to import a component in another page you need to defineComponent
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "NameOfVueComponent",
});

and in the page you want it to import or use
    import NameOfVueComponent from "src/components/NameOfVueComponent.vue";
         export default {
      components: { NameOfVueComponent },
     setup(){
        return{}
            }
                       }

you need to define it in the components and you can use it in you page
<NameOfVueComponent />

